# measuring and characterizing magnetic field of pulsed electromagnetic coil

Tags: electromagnetic

I'm trying to measure the characteristics of a kinda-high-powered pulsed electromagnetic coil. I'm trying to characterize different coil designs, and different pulse-generators. It's operating between the realm of single pulses, to low-frequency of about 5-10hz pulses, to some more complex patterns later. The coils are air-core, flat planar (pancake) coils. Pulse generator is a 50uF cap charged to 1-3kV, switched through the coil with an SCR. So how would you measure a magnetic field like this?

Comment: Hall sensor in case of electrical measurement. For more mechanical measurement you can use a permanent magnet attached to spring or force meter (works for dc pulses only).

Comment: What particular aspect of the magnetic field are you trying to measure and why?